# PHPExcel - write data to an existing XLSX file; Charts and Filters are lost

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an XLSX template, where in Worksheet1 raw data are located and in Worksheet2 these data are used for graphical evaluation (charts / privot tables). I want to load this XLSX file and the raw data should be overwritten, Worksheet2 should not be changed at all. I should receive the new XLSX file via mail. The whole thing works so far, except that in Worksheet2 all charts, filters etc. are gone - formulas are still there.

Here is my code:

```
// Load the XLSX file
$inputFileName = 'path/to/your/file.xlsx';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

// Get the active sheet
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

// Code for filling the sheet with data (same as before)
// ...

// Save the modified workbook to output
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_start();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
$excel = ob_get_clean();

// Send Mail with the modified workbook as an attachment
// ...

unlink($filename);

ob_end_clean();
```

The original XLSX file is loaded, filled and sent to me via mail. However, the charts and filters in Worksheet2 are lost.

I use the PHPExcel() library. Is there any way to make the charts in Worksheet2 not disappear? If not, does it work with PhpSpreadsheet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The PHPExcel library has been deprecated and replaced by PhpSpreadsheet, which is actively maintained and recommended for use. With PhpSpreadsheet, you can achieve the desired result of modifying the raw data in Worksheet1 while preserving the charts and filters in Worksheet2.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code using PhpSpreadsheet:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

// Load the XLSX file
$inputFileName = 'path/to/your/file.xlsx';
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

// Get the active sheet
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

// Code for filling the sheet with data (same as before)
// ...

// Save the modified workbook to output
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
ob_start();
$writer->save('php://output');
$excel = ob_get_clean();

// Send Mail with the modified workbook as an attachment
// ...

unlink($filename);

ob_end_clean();
```

By switching to PhpSpreadsheet, you should be able to retain the charts and filters in Worksheet2 while modifying the data in Worksheet1.